# Run-time error '9' when copying worksheet to another workbook

Tags: excel, runtime-error, worksheet, vba

I've been trying to write a macro to copy "Sheet1" from one workbook into another, but I keep getting a run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

```
Sub CopySheetToOtherWbk()

Dim CopyFromBook As Workbook
Dim CopyToWbk As Workbook
Dim ShToCopy As Worksheet

Set CopyFromBook = Workbooks("AllBugs.xlsx")
Set ShToCopy = CopyFromBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set CopyToWbk = Workbooks("YourFriendlyNeighborhoodTemplateWorksheet.xlsx")

ShToCopy.Copy After:=CopyToWbk.Sheets(CopyToWbk.Sheets.Count)

End Sub
```

The highlighted line is "Set CopyFromBook = Workbooks("AllBugs.xlsx")". Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Relatively new to VBA. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Workbooks` collection refers to all currently open workbooks. If the workbook isn't open you will need to do this first.

```
Set CopyFromBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Some Location\AllBugs.xlsx")
```

Comment: I tried that, and now I'm getting a Run-time error '1004'. It says the file couldn't be found. I copy-pasted the path to the file and did the same for the file name. I don't know what's going wrong here.

`Set CopyFromBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\my.name\Desktop\CopyTest\AllBugs.xlsx")`

Edit: forgot to add code

Comment: Some basic debugging required: Check the path, filename and EXTN again; create a simple procedure that just uses this Open statement; try it with a sample file of the C: drive, etc.. Make sure the workbook isn't open already.

Comment: Works now! I had missed it was .xlsm instead of .xlsx. Stupid mistake. Thanks for the help!

Comment: He, he, I guessed that ;)